# Best way to 'translate' an array?

Tags: php, arrays

So, I have an array that I want to 'transform' (only add some values of that array, to a different array with different keys).

What would be the best way to do this? I currently have a method that does this, but I think there's a better way to do this.

For example: an API returns this:

```
[
   'id' => 1,
   'title' => 'Response title',
   'message' => 'Here is a message',
   'clueless' => true,
   'need_help' => true
]
```

but for my front-end I need this:

```
[
       'task_id' => 1,
       'text' => 'Response title',
       'message' => 'Here is a message'
]
```

Note that the values are the same, but only they keys are different. Also, there's some values I don't need.

My current method for this looks like this:

```
public function toSpecificFormat($data) {
   return [
      'task_id' => $data['id'],
      'text' => $data['title'],
      'message' => $data['message']
   ];
}
```

Comment: Show us your best attempt(code) so we can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally pressed submit before I was finished. Here you go

Comment: Define *best*. And since your code is working, this question is out of topic for StackOverflow, but could be asked on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's just a simplified example, don't really know why I need to give a 'better' example for such a basic problem to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how many fields you really need to rewrite, you may want to create map of keys like this:

```
$src = [
   'id' => 1,
   'title' => 'Response title',
   'message' => 'Here is a message',
   'clueless' => true,
   'need_help' => true
];

$map = ['id' => 'task_id',
        'title' => 'text',
        'message' => 'messsage',
       ];

$result = [];
foreach($map as $from => $to) {
   $result[$to] = $src[$from];
}

print_r($result);
```

But if you got more keys to "rewrite" then this is more flexible approach than manual copying, but if one have just a few (say 2 or 3) then OP's code is perfectly sufficient and going way shown in my answer would be just a plain over-engineering.

Comment: In what is this solution *better* ? Providing code is nice, but explaining why is your solution better than OP's one would be better. However, you might get downvotes since this question is opinion-based and rather should be posted on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (OP's code is working and he wants to improve it)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it! @Cid this solution removes about 50 lines from my code, so that's why I chose it as an answer :)

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer to the question. When did OP ask to flip the keys and properties like you do with `$result`? To me it looked like OP want to just relabel Associative Array indexes, and `echo json_encode($assocArrayOrObject);`. The rich get richer. I'm not sure why at all in this case.